# How can I load a large amount of data in a UITableview without memory warnings?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I'm trying to create a custom view that can display a large amount of data, similar to the way UITableView is able to display many rows of data. Right now I'm displaying the data in a UIScrollView, but after I reload the data several times my app starts to receive memory warnings.

What's the right way to design a custom view to display a large amount of data, and how can I avoid these memory warnings?

Comment: Core Data would be a good start.

Comment: Well my psychic is not answering his phone atm to tell me more about your problem... hang in there i'll reply as soon as i reach him ;)

Comment: i am getting data from web server. i just want to understand UITableView mechanism

Comment: @user2311383 I rewrote your question based on your comments. Please edit if I've changed the meaning away from your real intent. Also, it'd be helpful if you post the relevant code. I think we can save this question yet.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't. UITableView loads only as many rows as it can fit on the screen. When it needs more rows it asks the data source for them. This gives the appearance that the table contains all the data without all the overhead of copying everything at once.

Comment: yes but my question is how it work in internally? and how UITableView mange large amount of data?

Comment: @user2311383 You asked how it handles large amounts of data. The answer, again, is that it doesn't handle large amounts of data. When cells are no longer visible (i.e. scrolled off the screen) they're recycled, so a table never needs more than a few dozen cells.

Comment: Yes i am displaying feed in UIScrollView which works fine but after loading so many feeds app give me Memory worming

Comment: Don't blame UITableView for that, the problem is in your code. Instruments can help you track down memory leaks and other problems.

Comment: @user2311383 Sorry -- just realized that you mean that you want to mimic the way tables work, not that a table is the problem. Same answer, though -- tables only maintain the cells they need to display and create others as they're needed. So, if you're creating lots of views or even one huge view and putting them all in a scroll view, that may be too much. Look at the delegate methods that UIScrollView provides if you want to try to follow UITableView's example. Or, just use a UITableView or UICollectionView.

Comment: I want to create custom view like UITableView using UIScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

When your `tableView` cell is too heavy means, it has `imageView` and more than one text label better create a custom cell by subclassing the `UITableView`.

Make sure that in custom cell the subview should be added only once and reused for cells. Just you need to sent the image of imageview or text of label. Even if you have so many cells in tableview the performance will be good.

And also make sure that if you are loading images from server don't fetch every time when you are setting image for cell. use image cache.

The following link might me useful for loading data to table view from server.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/4295/multithreading-and-grand-central-dispatch-on-ios-for-beginners-tutorial